# awk subtract value found with first and last line of a log

Tags: awk

I'm trying to find the total duration of an operation.
Within the logs I want to retrieve every line concerning a DELETE operation for a list of specific object name (lets says folders) containing elements (like files).
The logs reports each delete operation: in order to measure the duration of the Delete for a specific object, I can subtract the timestamp of the first to the one of last Delete.

I found a way to perform this operation but I would like to get your advices to make it look and perform better.

```
for name in $(cat List_to_Del) ; do
    grep $name access_log |
    grep "method=DELETE" |
    awk 'NR==1 ; END{print}' |
    awk -F, '{print $3}' |
    awk -F= '{print $2}' |
    paste -sd- - |
    bc |
    awk -F- '{print $NF}'
done
```

For loop. I'm looking at a list of deleted name and search them in my log.
I retrieve the full list of DELETE operation, name by name.
Then (first awk command) I only keep the first and last line for each name.
Then I just retrieve the field number 2 within the field number 3.
Then I use the paste command to write both values one line with the sign "-" as a delimiter, push it to bc and remove the minus sign.

Here is an example of logs:

```
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.235,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.236,method=PUT,name4,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.243,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.254,method=DELETE,name2,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.256,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.260,method=DELETE,name2,,,
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code, input, and output blocks then [edit] your question to fix them (format them all as "code blocks"). Also, don't cram all of your code onto a single line as that just makes it much harder for us to read.

Comment: I just did it for you so you can see how to do it in your next question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the expected output given the sample input you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
$4 == "method=DELETE" {
    name = $5
    time = $3
    sub(/.*=/,"",time)
    end[name] = time

    if ( !(name in beg) ) {
        beg[name] = time
    }
}
END {
    for (name in beg) {
        print name, end[name] - beg[name]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk access_log
name1 0.0210001
name2 0.00600004
```

If you really only wanted to analyze a target subset of the names in your log then it'd be:

```
$ cat List_to_Del
name2
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR==FNR {
    tgts[$0]
    next
}
{ name = $5 }
(name in tgts) && ($4 == "method=DELETE") {
    time = $3
    sub(/.*=/,"",time)
    end[name] = time

    if ( !(name in beg) ) {
        beg[name] = time
    }
}
END {
    for (name in beg) {
        print name, end[name] - beg[name]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk List_to_Del access_log
name2 0.00600004
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` for this as folows, let `file.txt` content be

```
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.235,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.236,method=PUT,name4,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.243,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.254,method=DELETE,name2,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.256,method=DELETE,name1,,,
16/Nov/2021:17:07:42,100,ts=1637078862.260,method=DELETE,name2,,,
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",|="}/method=DELETE/{if(flag){finish=$4}else{start=$4;flag=1}}END{print finish-start}' file.txt
```

output

```
0.0250001
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator (`FS`) is `,` or (`|`) `=`, thus ts value will go into column number 4 (1st: datetime, 2nd: seconds hundreds, 3rd: literal `ts`). For each line with `method=DELETE` if `flag` is set I set `finish` variable value to ts value, if `flag` is not yet set then I set `start` variable value to ts value. Finally (in `END`) I `print` difference between `finish` and `start`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: You know you're allowed to put some whitespace in your code.

Comment: @glennjackman but then just ANYBODY would be able to read it... :-).

Answer (score 0):

With a single pass through the log file, you can collect "last - first" for all names

```sh
awk -F'[,=]' '
    $6 != "DELETE" {next}
    !($7 in first) {first[$7] = $4}
    {last[$7] = $4}
    END {for (name in first) print name, last[name] - first[name]}
' log
```

```
name1 0.0210001
name2 0.00600004
```

Then, you can use List_to_Del and a single grep to filter out the ones you do/don't want

```sh
$ cat List_to_Del
name1

$ awk -F'[,=]' '
      $6 != "DELETE" {next}
      !($7 in first) {first[$7] = $4}
      {last[$7] = $4}
      END {
          for (name in first)
              print name, last[name] - first[name]
      }
  ' log | grep -v -w -F -f List_to_Del
name2 0.00600004
```

If that filter output is backwards, remove `-v`